# Can two classes inheriting the same base class use eachother's functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've been stuck on this problem based on inheritance in C++ and I'm unsure if my approach is even correct.

```
class A
{
private:
   string s;
public: 
   A(string s);
   virtual ~A;
   virtual void set(string s);
   virtual string get();
 };

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
   void set(string s);
   string get();
}

class C : public virtual A
{
public:
   void set(string s);
}

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
   void set(string s);
}
```

When calling the set method from D my code should call the set method of C but then somehow call the get method of B while inside of the set method of C. I don't understand how that's actually possible since B and C are completely unrelated other than they both inherit the same base class. I'm sure it's an issue with how I've done these headers but every solution I've attempted has only resulted in compiling errors.

D's set method is simply

```
D::set(string s){
   C::set(s);
   D::set(s);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You are not calling any methods, actually you have not defined any method in the code you show

Comment: That cannot be done type safe. There could be objects of type B which are not of type C, then you cannot call C::set. Doing unsafe casts that could be done, but as said, that won't always work.

Comment: Is the intention here really that every one of those member functions is private? If so, there's very little that can be done here.

Comment: Isn't this the diamond of death?

Comment: @noobius yes it is, this is for an assignment and the instructor intentionally made the design flawed for later essay questions.

Comment: @noobius -- it is the classic diamond hierarchy. Whether that's "the diamond of death" depends on what RPG you're playing. <g>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as pointed out in a comment, all of these member functions are private, so none of them can call any of the others. Assuming that that's a typo, and they are all in fact marked public (or each class is a friend of all the others, definitely not a good idea), this can be done in a fairly straightforward way.

In `D::set()` you want to call `C::set()`. That's easy. Just do it:

```
void D::set(string s) {
    C::set(s);
}
```

And now you want `C::set()` to call `B::get()`. You can't do that directly, because `C` doesn't know about `B`. But, since `get()` is a virtual function, you can call it and rely on virtual dispatch to get the only overrider, namely, `B::get()`. That is:

```
void C::set(string s) {
    std::string res = get();
}
```

That works because this particular `C` object is, in fact, part of a `D` object, and every `D` object has a `B` sub-object that overrides `A::get()`. In a plain old `C` object, that call to `get()` would call `A::get()`.

Just to be clear: this is a very confusing class hierarchy, so don't be embarrassed about being lost. On the other hand, maybe being lost means that it's just too complicated, and that there's a design problem here.

Comment: `C::set` is private though so it cannot be called from `D`.

Comment: @eerorika -- everything is private, so nothing can be called. As I said, a very confusing class hierarchy. <g> That's undoubtedly a typo.

Comment: It was a mistake, I meant to make them public and i just fixed that. This is for an assignment and it was explicitly stated for the hierarchy to be setup like this. I didn't know calling get in C would invoke B's get in this situation, thank you!